# Is it possible to add a custom spellchecker function to an HTML textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

## Question:

I'd like to know if it is possible to add a custom spellchecker function to a Textarea.

## Background:

I am currently using bootstrap-vue's `b-form-textarea` component to display a textarea that accepts a list of values from a user.

I am already validating `state` and displaying whether the textarea is valid or invalid. However, I'd like like to show a "red squiggly" (similar to spellcheck) under each "invalid" entry.

As an example, user enters (up to 1,000) car manufacturers

- "Toyota, Honda, Dodge, Harley Davidson".

I'd like to display that "Harley Davidson" is an invalid car manufacturer.

It'd be nice to leverage the spellchecker's "red squiggly" to denote an "invalid" entry. If this is not possible would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You can try creating a div with `contenteditable` and every car make is `span` and you can style accordingly.

Comment: I don't think is possible with something that is based on <textarea>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've read, it does not seem possible to add the spellchecker functionality I required to a textarea. What I ended up using instead was a package, found in npm, called "[vue-codemirror](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-codemirror)". It is an extension of the [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) project.

Using CodeMirror, I was able to add gutters with red error icons next to each line (similiar to an IDE displaying syntax errors). In my opinion, the CodeMirror documentation was lackluster and I spent more time looking at source code than I wanted. However, it does seem like very powerful tool.

**Notes:**

- I am using Vue 2.x. As such, I was not able to use the [latest version](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-codemirror) of vue-codemirror (which requires Vue 3).
- [Vue-codemirror 4.x](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-codemirror/tree/v4.0.6) uses [CodeMirror 5](https://codemirror.net/5/doc/manual.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use String method(split) to transfer input text into array, and use the method of map to process the array.